# Aptana Studio 3 - Lost Remote Sites

Tags: aptana3

I am having a recurring and very annoying problem when using Aptana Studio 3 (Linux Mint 12).

I use the remote tab to keep track of several FTP sites but every few months, the list disappears completely and I have to manually re-enter the details for each connection.

[image]

Has anyone encountered this before / know if there's a way to retrieve them?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me recently when updating Aptana 3.  However, a refresh of the remote pane somehow found all my old remote connex.